# Drawing many circles using D3 Javascript based on a particular JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I am trying to draw some circles using D3 Javascript library based on the JSON file format that I have. Here is the JSON file:

```
{"Resources":[{"resource":[{"name":"A"}]}],
              "literals":[{"literal":[{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"}]}]}
```

This is my code for drawing three circles based on this JSON format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample2</title>
<style>

.node {
      stroke: #fff;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 1000;//960,
height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
   .charge(-120)
   .linkDistance(30)
   .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);

d3.json("folder/newjsonsample6.json", function(error, graph) {

// Resource 
   force 
    .nodes(graph.Resources[0].resource)
    .start();
    var resourceNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.Resources[0].resource)
            .append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 20)
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(2); })
            .call(force.drag);
        resourceNode.append("title")
            text(function(d) { return d.name; });

       force.on("tick", function() {
       resourceNode.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

       resourceNode.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
           .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    });
// Literals
   force
   .nodes(graph.literals[0,0].literal) 
   .start();

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.literals[0,0].literal)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1); })
        .call(force.drag);

        node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        force.on("tick", function() {
      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

         node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

        });
        });

        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

As you may notice, I drew the resources circle and then the literals circles (The literals circles are three). It shows me in the canvas that there are only the three literals circles. I cant find the resources circle. Could anyone please help me to find what the problem is. Why am I not able to display the resource circle however the code to draw the resource circle is similar to the code for drawing the literals circles. Your help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The circle is created, it just never appears at the correct position as you're overwriting the function that sets that (the on tick function). It should work if you define that as follows.

```
force.on("tick", function() {
   resourceNode.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
   node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Your help is very much appreciated. I could see it now moving around with the other circles. Thank you very much.